# Вывод свойств фильтрации под заголовок из умного фильтра Bitrix

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

На странице каталога подключен  компонент **catalog.smart.filter** . Фильтрует товары ajax-ом.
Необходимо вывести свойства фильтрации под заголовок раздела. Пример исполнения http://joxi.net/D2PjVdVSpQ7ver . т.е после выбора в select активного option выводить его под заголовок.

> Как это реализовать ? Куды копать и к чему цеплятся ?

Попытался воплоить это таким образом:  привязался к функции

> JCSmartFilter.prototype.selectDropDownItem

она вызывается в шаблоне  фильтра  при изменении select

```
<select id="<?= $arResult["FILTER_NAME"]."_".$arItem["ID"]?>" name="<?=$arCur["CONTROL_NAME_ALT"]?>" onchange="smartFilter.selectDropDownItem(this, '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arResult["FILTER_NAME"]."_".$arItem["ID"])?>')">
```

Нахожу выбранный option  c **data-role="currentOption"** и пытаюсь его через  JQ append() добавить в блок под заголовком.

### Но тут встречаются проблемы:

1. Свойство фильтрации добавляется быстрее чем фильтруется Ajax-ом,
   после того как Ajax все выполнил  свойство пропадает . Решить можно
   задержкой  или добавлять после как ajax запрос завершится
2. Самая главная проблема . При выборе  2-ого  свойства фильтрации  , 1
   пропадает

Comment: Добавлять нужно однозначно после выполнения аякс-запроса. Приведите полный код того что вы написали для этого и желательно с кодом шаблона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все легче чем казалось . В массиве компонента  передаются параметры фильтраци $GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"] . Далее зная XML_ID , можно  дернуть свойство по API Bitrix через CIBlockPropertyEnum::GetList и вывести куда надо

Comment: Можно пожалуйста, чуть поподробнее раскрыть найденное вами решение?:)

Comment: Что именно не понятно ?